# Parcelable android

Tags: android, parcelable

```
package com.iconasystems.android.models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 2/15/2016.
 */
@ParseClassName("Lock")

public class Lock extends ParseObject implements Parcelable {
    private String simNumber;
    private User owner;
    private String authToken;
    private String state;
    private String id;
    private String doorName;
    public Lock() {
    }

    public Lock(Parcel parcel){
        this.doorName = parcel.readString();
        this.authToken = parcel.readString();
        this.simNumber = parcel.readString();
        this.state = parcel.readString();
        this.id = parcel.readString();

    }

    // Some getters and setters

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(doorName);
        parcel.writeString(authToken);
        parcel.writeString(simNumber);
        parcel.writeString(state);
        parcel.writeString(id);

    }

    final Creator<Lock> CREATOR = new Creator<Lock>() {
        @Override
        public Lock createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new Lock(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public Lock[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Lock[i];
        }
    };


}
```

A Lock is owned by a User (has its own model) so its has an attribute owner of type User. My major problem is writing the user object into the parcel. Is there a way of writing custom types into a parcel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of writing custom types into a parcel.

Yes. Your `User` class has to implement `Parcelable` and then in your `writeToParcel` method you can use `parcel.writeParcelable(user, i)`

`Parcel` can also work with classes implementing `Serializable` using `parcel.writeSerializable`. This requires significantly less work on the your part but because `Serializable` uses reflection, it'll come with a performance penalty.

Comment: Or, it could implement `Serializable` and then use `writeSerializable()`. `Parcelable` is faster when executing, though.

Comment: when i am reading i need to specify a ClassLoader is it right to use the system class loader.

Comment: @christoandrew I don't know what you mean by system class loader but if you're trying to `readParcelable` on your `User` class you'd pass in `User.class.getClassLoader()`

Comment: this is what i meant ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()